# how to put image in the center of the button

Tags: java, android

I want to put the image in the center of the button.I want to use only linear layout.Any help will be great.Here is my layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >
  <Button
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use android:drawable(direction here eg Top,Bottom)="@drawable/whatever".. in the button

Comment: I have already paste code.Please check it.

Comment: hack your way around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So you want the image at the center : *`Simplest way to achieve this is`***

---

### Steps

1. There is no need of `linear layout`
2. Use a image(`.png` or`.jpg`) and use it as a `drawable`
3. Set that `drawable` resource as the background for the `button`

Comment: I want to use linear layout.Can you solve this using linear layout?

Comment: @ Soham .... You can also remove the `button` and set the `linearlayout` background with the image and make linear layout clickable !

Comment: yes,you are absolutely right.But the client wants buttons there and he is very technical person,that I can't help.LOL

Comment: @ Soham .... Just Use the `LinearLayout`, make it `clickable`, set the `background` for it. Finally keep the button and use the opacity to set the `visibility`.... But here `Relative layout` is suitable in place of `linearLayout` ! ... let me know if you are in doubt !

Comment: No you are saying right,I know.I have solve my problem,so that's why I am not changing anything. Thanks for all your help.Much appreciated.

Comment: @ Soham ... You are welcome ! ... If you find my answer helpful mark it as accepted or if you have found a better solution post as your answer and mark that as accepted .. So that it is helpful for someone else looking for same query that you have asked ! .... Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I have done this.This can be solved by using Imagebutton instead of Button

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >
   <ImageButton
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/home"
/>
```